# Query to get permissions given to users on syslogins table sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

My aim is to fetch the list of users who have any access on syslogins table.

sp_helprotect 'syslogins'

Can someone provide a query for this?

Comment: are you saying that `sp_helprotect` doesn't give you what you're looking for?  have you looked at the source code for `sp_helprotect` to see where it's getting the data it displays - general idea being that you could roll your own query to display the data you're looking for

Comment: From the output of sp_helprotect 'syslogins', I want only those fields where column='password'

Comment: ok, so take a look at the source code for `sp_helprotect` and roll your own queries to produce the desired output; if you've tried this but still not getting what you want, then post your query(s), the current output and the desired output

Comment: That's the thing. I am not able to find/create any query for that.

Comment: Where can I see the source code of sp_helprotect

Comment: ask your DBA to pull a copy of the source code for `sp_helpprotect`; the code can be pulled from the `installmaster` script or from the system tables (via `sp_helptext`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202358/discussion-between-nibba-and-markp).